# PCI Scan warning us of cross-site scripting

Tags: security, scripting, cross-site

We received a scan report that lists a number of items on our website that never previously popped up as an issue. What in the following code is a vulnerability to cross-site scripting?

```
<?php $Get_url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
<div class="event-social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
                       'facebook-share-dialog', 
                       'width=626,height=436'); 
                        return false;">
                        <img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-facebook.gif" alt="Share on Facebook" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?&url=<?php echo $Get_url; ?>&via=niagaraparks"><img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"
                        onclick="window.open('http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $Get_url; ?>',
                        'popupwindow',
                        'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400').focus();"><img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-googleplus.gif" alt="Google+" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here:

```
 <li class="social"><a href="http://blog.xxxxxxxxxx.com/?feed=rss2" target="_blank" id="rss"><img src="/images/homepage/icon-blog.png" alt="RSS" /></a></li>
```

And then several points in our contact form page (lastname parameter, emailc paramter, etc.:

```
<div class="line"><label for="firstname">First Name</label>:        
        <input id="firstname" maxlength="55" name="firstname" type="text" value="<?=$_REQUEST["firstname"] ?>" /></div>
    <div class="line"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label>:
        <input id="lastname" maxlength="55" name="lastname"  type="text" value="<?=$_REQUEST["lastname"] ?>" /></div>
    <div class="line"><label for="email">E-mail</label>:
        <input id="email" maxlength="100" name="email"  type="text" value="<?=$_REQUEST["email"] ?>"/></div>
            <div class="line"><label for="emailc">Confirm E-mail</label>:
        <input id="emailc" maxlength="100" name="emailc"  type="text" value="<?=$_REQUEST["emailc"] ?>"/></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**More Details**

I've made some changes that I hope solves my problem:

```
<?php $Get_url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$Get_url = urlencode($Get_url);
?>
<div class="event-social">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
                   'facebook-share-dialog', 
                   'width=626,height=436'); 
                    return false;">
                    <img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-facebook.gif" alt="Share on Facebook" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?&url=<?php echo $Get_url; ?>&via=niagaraparks"><img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"
                    onclick="window.open('http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $Get_url; ?>',
                    'popupwindow',
                    'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400').focus();"><img src="/images/events-calendar/cal-googleplus.gif" alt="Google+" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And for the contact form, I had already used strip_tags when echoing the input variables into an email, does that not avoid the problem? Or do I need to escape the variable at the input as well? For now, I've changed my strip_tags or htmlspecialchars:

```
$emailContents .= "<tr style='padding:10px;'><td style='padding:3px 10px;'><strong>E-mail:</strong> </td><td style='padding:3px 10px;'>" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
```

But the scanner seems to be concerned with the input code:

```
            <input id="email" maxlength="100" name="email"  type="text" value="<?=$_REQUEST["email"] ?>"/></div>
```

I'm not sure how I would modify those lines to escape/sanitize that input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

If you add parameters to the end of your URL then $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will put them into your script. It's a possible cross-site scripting issue because you're then echoing out the value on the page, meaning that visitors to your site can change the page's content.

Comment: Thanks Scoop, could you point me in the direction to correcting these issues? Is there another way to insert the parameters?

Comment: I've added more details above after some attempts to fix. Currently watching a number of videos but having a hard time finding an example that shows input.

Comment: It would all depend on your application and how it works. However, assuming that you're not doing anything with the URL than targeting physical pages, you could remove everything in the URL after ".php" for example.

Comment: What about the contact form? Am I right in thinking it's a false positive that the scanner is flagging our input tags? We use htmlspecialchars when echoing into the email in the php, and it's my understanding that you don't want to sanitize the input data?

Comment: Again, that would depend heavily on what your site does. I would ordinarily suggest that all user input should be sanitized. If your end users typically input a standard message then sanitizing it won't change anything. However if JavaScript is submitted then you'd want to strip that out / stop it rendering as JavaScript on the page. You should retain complete control of all content shown on your site - even when it's dynamic.

Comment: Well I'm showing you what my site does. It collects strings in input tags, as shown above, then echos them out into an email. Every echo'd variable uses HTMLspecialchars. But this scanner is taking issue with the input tags. How would I go about correcting that? Where is the risk if the variables are sanitized when printed?

Comment: So, I've read up a bit more and have modified the form to include the following at the top:

`$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["firstname"]);
    $lastname  = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["lastname"]);
    $email     = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $emailc     = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["emailc"]);
    $subject   = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["subjectid"]);
    $message   = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["comment"]);
    $subject2  = "Thank you for your email";`

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: That will certainly help, Nathan. How far you take this is up to you / budget I guess. For example, if you're only expecting an email address in the email field then you can ensure that it only contains letters, numbers and full stops, and an @symbol.